# LEFT JOIN doesn't work with count

Tags: sql, count, group-by, ms-access-2007, left-join

I have a problem with my query:

```
SELECT table1.Name,
       COUNT(*)  
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2 ON table2.Name_all = table1.Name
GROUP BY table1.Name
```

It shows and counts a names from table1. I want to join all names from table2 which do not exist in table1.

Maybe someone knows what I am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your looking for values in table2, that don't exist in table1 - do you need any additional data from table1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your description you seem to mean this, which is a list of name_all that does not match table1 name.

```
SELECT table2.Name_all
FROM table2
LEFT JOIN table1 ON table2.Name_all = table1.Name
WHERE table1.Name Is Null
```

If you need a count as well, you can say:

```
SELECT table2.Name_all, Count(table2.Name_all) AS CountOf
FROM table2 
LEFT JOIN table1 ON table2.Name_all= table1.Name
WHERE table1.Name Is Null
GROUP BY table2.Name_all;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

This query will fetch common names from table 1 and table 2. It will also fetch names from table 2 which are not there in table 1.

```
SELECT table1.Name,
       table2.Name,
       COUNT(*)  
FROM table2  
LEFT JOIN table1 
    ON table2.Name_all = table1.Name
GROUP BY table1.Name, table2.Name
```

Let me if this works.

Comment: Its because in the select there is no column from table-2. I have changed my query.

Answer (score 0):

I would do a simple `in` check then

```
SELECT table1.Name,
FROM table1
WHERE table1.Name In (SELECT table2.Name_all FROM table2)
GROUP BY table1.Name
```

There are other ways, but without more information this is a simple way t